# Catch an exception in python... but still continue

Tags: python, exception, logging

**tl;dr** I use `try: ... except Exception as err: pass` but the code still stops when an exception is raised, even if it shouldn't.

I am running a transformation algorithm on a csv. And one of the transformations takes into account the existence of a column's values in a database. If it doesn't exist, I raise an exception like this :

`2019-05-15 16:36:37,095 - root - WARNING - The data in 'section_code' either doesn't exist in the raw data or hasn't been correctly encoded. The following strings caused the encoding error : '['398', 'die']'`

I know it isn't good to use this practice of `try: ... except: pass`, but I want my code to continue on transforming the file while only logging the errors/warnings where they appear.

Here's how my code is encased in the `try...except` block

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        # Initiate logger
        logging.basicConfig(
            level="DEBUG",
            format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

        # Business code ...

    except FileNotFoundError as f_err:
        logging.exception(f_err)
    except AzureMissingResourceHttpError as az_err:
        logging.exception(az_err)
    except TypeError as t_err:
        pass
        logging.warning(t_err)
```

So my question is: why does the `pass` statement not have the wanted effect, and how do I implement this behavior?

Comment: `pass` Is really for place-holder code for when statements are required, but you haven't coded them in yet. If you're just throwing the exception to the logger, why not just remove the `pass` statement?

Comment: You can remove the pass statement.

Comment: What you want is Visual Basic's `on error resume next`, and there is no such thing in Python. (Which is a good thing; it forces you to think about exactly where errors may occur, and how they should be handled.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an exception occurs, the code immediately jumps to the exception handler and resumes the code *after* the exception.  It doesn't go back and continue where it left off in the code.

To fix, you have to limit the try/except around the line of code whose exception is to be ignored.

Comment: That means, whenever I want to implement the behavior of logging but not stopping, I have to encase the right lines of code and not the global calling functions? That's really tedious! Is there a way to be smart about it?

Comment: If you just have a global function that aborts on an error, and you can't change the internals of the function, no.  The `except` has to catch the error at a location that allows the algorithm to continue.  For example, a try/except can't encase a `for line in file: do_something('line')`, it has to encase just `do_something('line')`.  Then if it fails it can still continue with the next line.